# How can I add theme support for my custom keyboard?

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out how to add themes support for my custom keyboard. 
 The idea is that the user should be able to download the themes as .apk files from market and 
 apply them to my keyboard.

I can't understand how an app - the keyboard - can access files(drawables) from other app - the theme app.

What is your experience with themes? Could you give me a point to start?

Thank you